# Relation between stochastic and deterministic big O

Tags: probability, asymptotics, weak-convergence

Could you help me to clarify the relation between stochastic and non-stochastic Big O notation? Suppose I have a sequence of real-valued random variables $\{X_n\}_n$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Suppose I have shown that

$$
(*) \exists \text{ } a>0 \text{ such that } \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n\geq a)=0
$$

Moreover, we know that $\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq a)=O(1)$ by the properties of the probability measure.

Does (*) imply $X_n=O_p(1)$? Why?